# SQL Regex get phone number

Tags: sql-server, regex

I want to get the phone number of a text string that meets certain conditions:

- 9 characters (numbers)
- You can only start at 9,8,7,6

I tried with the expression:

```
'^\(?(9|8|7|6)\)?([0-9]{8}))$'
```

in the following function:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @validchars VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str = 'TESTING1234 997711056'
SET @validchars = '^\(?(9|8|7|6)\)?([0-9]{8}))$' 

WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @validchars + '%',@str) > 0
SET @str=REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str ,PATINDEX('%'+ @validchars +'%',@str), 1) ,'')


SELECT @str
```

I need to get 997711056 but I always get the complete text string. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) is not a regex function. You can only use a limited set of pattern identifiers and wildcards with it. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> % : Any string of zero or more characters.
>   _ (underscore) : Any single character.
>   [] : Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
>   [^] : Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).

The following will match nine digits in a row, starting with 6, 7, 8, or 9:

```
SET @validchars = '[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Your use of [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) is also incorrect. It looks like your code is attempting to eliminate characters of the number from the string. Here is how to get the string with the number removed:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @validchars VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str = 'TESTING1234 997711056 sdfgdfg'
SET @validchars = '[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
DECLARE @idx INT
SET @idx = PATINDEX('%'+ @validchars +'%',@str)
IF @idx > 0 AND 
    (@idx = LEN(@str)-8
    OR PATINDEX(SUBSTRING(@str,@idx+9,1),'[0-9]')=0)
    SET @str=REPLACE(@str,SUBSTRING(@str ,PATINDEX('%'+ @validchars +'%',@str), 9),'')
ELSE SET @str = ''
SELECT @str
```

You state you want to retrieve just the number out of the string; here is how to do that:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @validchars VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str = 'TESTING1234 997711056 sdfgdfg'
SET @validchars = '[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
DECLARE @idx INT
SET @idx = PATINDEX('%'+ @validchars +'%',@str)
IF @idx > 0 AND 
    (@idx = LEN(@str)-8
    OR PATINDEX(SUBSTRING(@str,@idx+9,1),'[0-9]')=0)
    SET @str=SUBSTRING(@str ,PATINDEX('%'+ @validchars +'%',@str), 9)
ELSE SET @str = ''
SELECT @str
```

Comment: but checking ... I still returns the same string: S

Comment: @csotelo Edited answer to show how to get the string with or without the number and match exactly nine digits.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) 

---- returns 997711056
SET @str= 'TESTING1234 997711056'
---- returns NULL
--SET @str= 'TESTING1234 0997711056'
---- returns NULL
--SET @str= 'TESTING1234 9977110560'
---- returns 997711056
--SET @str= '997711056'
---- returns NULL
--SET @str= '0997711056'
---- returns NULL
--SET @str= '9977110560'
---- returns NULL
--SET @str= 'test'

DECLARE @pat NVARCHAR(100) = '%[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
DECLARE @len INT = 9
DECLARE @ind INT = PATINDEX(@pat, @str)

SELECT  CASE WHEN
            ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@str, @ind - 1, 1)) = 1 OR ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@str, @ind + @len, 1)) = 1 THEN NULL 
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING(@str, NULLIF(@ind, 0), @len)
        END
```

`PATINDEX` is not intended to match regular expressions, for it's usage read the [MSDN article about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

If you just want to extract the number you don't need the `WHILE` loop.

For the possibility when there is no 9-digit number starting with numbers 6-9 in the string, this code will return `NULL`.

Comment: The only problem is when there are 9 + phone characters ... You may be strict on the quantity? (without substring)

Comment: I thought there must be exactly 9 digits... For sample text `TESTING1234 997711056888 some text` you would want to return `997711056888`?

Comment: in the case of "... 997711056888" should return null. I need only numbers need to make sure they are 9 digit numbers.

Comment: I added some extra test samples, I believe it now delivers expected result, check it out.