# Extracting phone numbers from a string using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

Actually I want to catch the phone numbers in a string. On some websites its mentioned that use this Regexpression ([ref](http://vb.net.bigresource.com/RegEx-International-Domestic-Phone-Numbers--8E1qbP9nC.html))

```
^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$
```

But it's not working on the normal sql query. Here's the syntax:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (mystring, '^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$')
```

I am doing something wrong here ?

Comment: I hope this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740423/sql-regex-get-phone-number may help you. Please check once

Comment: Please consider posting the actual errors or erroneous results you get with your current query.

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` is an Oracle function. It's not available in MySQL and SQL Server. Speaking of which, what DB are you using? They are different products.

Answer (score 0):

\d and \s don't exist in MySQL.  Use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` and `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` or simply .

Some other things are fixed here:

```
str REGEXP '^([+][0-9]{1,2})?([(][0-9]{3}[)]|[0-9]{3})[-. ][0-9]{4}$'
```